# Image blob to base64

Tags: image, go, base64, blob

Im trying to read a blob from database and show it to browser as a base64 image (I think its the only way to show it)

My code is the following

```
    rows, err := database.Conn.Query("SELECT a.id, a.name, a.creationdata, b.logo, c.name FROM guilds a, cloaka_guilds b, players c WHERE a.ownerid = c.id AND b.guild_id = a.id ORDER BY creationdata DESC")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    guild_list := []*Guild{}
    for rows.Next() {
        guild := &Guild{}
        rows.Scan(&guild.Id, &guild.Name, &guild.Creationdata, &guild.Logo, &guild.Owner)
        guild.Logo_str = base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(guild.Logo)
        guild_list = append(guild_list, guild)
    }
    return guild_list, nil
```

b.logo holds an image []byte. Im sure of that. To be even more sure IntelliJ IDEA shows on the database row

> 88x88 Image 1.68K PNG

On the browser im rendering with something like

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,[[ $element.Logo ]]">
```

But something is clearly wrong since I get this

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,[137%2080%2078%2071%2013%2010%2026%20.........]">
```

As for the struct guild.Logo is []byte type

Comment: How are you passing the output to the browser? The output you *are* showing are the raw bytes with `%20` representing spaces.

Comment: The output definitely looks like the escaped representation of a byte slice being printed as a string.

Answer (score 1):

To present image as a base64 you do not need `[[` symbols. Here is an [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQV....
```

And [here is how it will look](https://jsfiddle.net/v619u8kd/1/).

Take a look at the data you get from your database. It should be a [byteArray](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/) or something that you can convert to byteArray. Having a byteArray you can base64 encode it with:

```
sEnc := b64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(byteArr)
```

Take a look at my <kbd>[Go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/P0heGBXSvm)</kbd> to see how I got the abovementioned base64 image.